# Python Selenium for Web Scraping not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, findelement

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.environ['PATH'] += "C:\\Users\\czoca\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject4\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.teintes.fr/p/recapitulatif.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
myelement1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Autoriser")
myelement = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Carens III")
myelement1.click()
myelement.click()
```

This is giving me this error:
""Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\czoca\PycharmProjects\imagesscraping\main.py", line 9, in 
myelement1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Autoriser")
^^
NameError: name 'By' is not defined[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cHQ8.png)

Comment: Добавьте `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the import of 'By' from the package selenium. You can import it like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

You can look up more details about selenium on the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following import to your file:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the By module from Selenium in order to use it ( I agree that it is not obvious at first time), by simply adding this line
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

You will also probably need thoses packages  :

```
# Import required packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
```

Hope I helped you

Have a good day